# Join two columns data with +- sign in between

Tags: pandas, join, concatenation, standard-deviation

[Dataframe screenshot of multiindex error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoZAK.png)I have four city data with mean and standard deviation and column names are respective city names with the suffix mean or sdev.

I want to join the mean and standard deviation data of each city and save them in the respective column of the city. In the targeted column where the mean and standard deviation is combined, it should have in between the `±` sign.

[image]

```
1  Gulzarpet_mean Amravati_mean Vizag_mean Gulzarpet_sdev Amravati_sdev Vizag_sdev
2            20.2         25.5         NaN           05.9          07.4        NaN
3            12.7         14.8        56.7           12.3          15.9        7.3
```

And I want my output either as python output or in excel format as shown below:

```
1  Gulzarpet  Amravati      Vizag 
2  20.2±5.9   25.5±7.4        NaN
3  12.7±12.3  14.8±15.9  56.7±7.3
```

I have no idea how to combine column data with different names and how to put `±` in between.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.astype(str).T.groupby(df.T.index.str.split('_').str[0]).agg('±'.join).T
```

Output:

```
    Amravati  Gulzarpet     Vizag
1                                
2   25.5±7.4   20.2±5.9   nan±nan
3  14.8±15.9  12.7±12.3  56.7±7.3
```

Comment: I am getting this error:- Can only use .str accessor with Index, not MultiIndex. I am uploading my dataframe screenshot because after reset_index of dataframe, I am not able to resolve error.